# A precise definition of macroscopic and microscopic objects

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, thermodynamics

What are the formal definitions of "macroscopic object" and "microscopic object". How can one differentiate between them? I mean, is there any fixed condition by which we can distinguish between them?

Comment: Anything not visible to naked eye is microscopic i think , i am not too sure about this though.

Comment: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/macroscopic

Comment: @Gowtham Everything is microscopic to blind people!

Comment: There's also [mesoscopic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mesoscopic_physics), which is between microscopic and macroscopic.

Comment: @Jim Can you tell me what is the range of size of the objects to be considered as macroscopic or microscopic ?

Comment: Basically, "macroscopic" is everything visible that isn't "microscopic".  I'm relatively confident that the term "microscopic" was coined first, shortly after the invention of the microscope, and then "macroscopic" was chosen as the antonym, as it were.

Comment: These terms are just based on your frame of reference.  Anything could be termed microscopic or macroscopic depending on what it's compared to.  You can easily look up the formal dictionary definition if that is what you're looking for.

Comment: For macroscopic, I find the definition 'anything that is visible to the naked eye' pretty flawed, because the air in a room is not visible to the naked eye but still we do study it macroscopically in physics. The point that @MichaelMcGriff makes, makes much more sense to me. Earth is macroscopic relative to us, but relative to the sun is microscopic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suspect this will be closed as "opinion based". I don't believe there is a canonical answer. Usually microscopic scale relates to phenomena that occur on a level much smaller than the system under consideration (atoms in a crystal when you are thinking about the crystal, for example).

There is an analogy with micro- and macro-economics. Micro-economics describes how individuals make economic decisions (spend, save, etc). Macro-economics describes how the system ("the economy" of a city, country, world) evolves as a result of the micro behavior.

They are almost always related - with one being the aggregate of the other. And they may require a different level of effort to observe - although I would not say it's necessarily "naked eye vs aided eye".

For example, when you consider the evolution of a galaxy, the motion of the moons around the planets in the solar systems may be considered "microscopic" - "small compared to the scale of the system under consideration". This means it may not be possible to set an absolute limit on the size where "microscopic" becomes "macroscopic".

Comment: can you be please more explanatory in terms of physics? I mean if you can tell me what is the range of size of the objects to be considered as macroscopic or microscopic ?

Comment: No I can't - sorry. When you consider the evolution of a galaxy, the motion of the moons around the planets in the solar systems may be considered "microscopic" - "small compared to the scale of the system under consideration".

Answer (score 0):

Mesoscopic physics is a branch of science which is in between microscopic and macroscopic physics. In this branch, objects of sizes in between 100  to 10000 nm is taken into consideration(from the size of a virus to a bacterium). However, this is not defined precisely. This new branch of physics, evolved about 10 years ago, is now an exciting field of research in physics. It has many scopes------nano fabrication, mesoscopic brain dynamics,etc.